# How to properly use Person Profile API for Amazon Alexa skill in Python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

So I'm trying to develop a skill in Alexa that uses voice recognition. I have the setting enabled on my end, but the problem is grabbing the necessary information in Python. I've read [this](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/request-recognized-speaker-contact-information.html) and also read the example in [JavaScript](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-cookbook/blob/master/feature-demos/skill-demo-person-profile/lambda/index.js). How do I call the Alexa to run the voice recognition service in python? I'm trying to basically translate the JavaScript code in that one link to Python.

While this isn't what I'm exactly trying to accomplish it starts somewhere.

```py
class SomeIntentHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
    def can_handle(self, handler_input):
        return ask_utils.is_intent_name("SomeIntentHandler")(handler_input)

    def handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> Response
        person = handler_input.request_envelope.context.system.person
        consentToken = handler_input.request_envelope.context.system.apiAccessToken
        if(person):
            speak_output = "Grabbing profile"
        else:
            speak_output = "Not a person"
        return (
            handler_input.response_builder
                .speak(speak_output)
                .ask(speak_output)
                .response
        )
```

My output is basically saying that it is an error.

Answer (score 2):

You could certainly take a look at the sample code for the [Address API in python](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-python/tree/master/samples/GetDeviceAddress), which is a bit similar to Alexa Customer Profile API.

But in general, as you shared in sample code above, your code should have handler classes for your skill's intents. And within each classes, you need to have the following 2 methods where you have access to the handler_input. That is:

1. ```
   can_handle(self, handler_input)
   ```
2. ```
   handle(self, handler_input)
   ```

And since this code is a snippet of lambda_funtion.py, I assume that you also including below code to skillBuilder object:
`sb.add_request_handler(SomeIntentHandler())`

If you are using ASK SDK for python You can find additional information on how to implement [the Customer Profile API on this page](https://alexa-skills-kit-python-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/SERVICE_CLIENTS.html#upsserviceclient), including some code samples.

Assuming skill is properly configured to request customer contact information and permission as documented [here](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/request-customer-contact-information-for-use-in-your-skill.html)

I would also to try to check any relevant cloud Watch logs for any potential runtime errors in your code.